# Google Fit API - No Callback Response

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to integrate Sensors API from Google Fit APIs. I am building the google client but there is no callback on any status.

Here is my code:

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {

        if (mClient == null && checkPermissions()) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Building Fitness Client");

            mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(
                            new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                                @Override
                                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                                    // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                    findFitnessDataSources();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                    // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                    // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                    if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                    } else if (i
                                            == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                        Log.i(TAG,
                                                "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    )
                    .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                                    result.toString());
                            Snackbar.make(
                                    MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_view),
                                    "Exception while connecting to Google Play services: " +
                                            result.getErrorMessage(),
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

In LOGCAT, I can see log "Building Fitness Client". After that, it's all blank. No error. Nothing.
LOGCAT:

```
04-13 07:21:40.964  13226-13226/com.hbeat.hbeat I/BasicSensorsApi﹕ Ready
04-13 07:21:40.964  13226-13226/com.hbeat.hbeat I/BasicSensorsApi﹕ Building Fitness Client
04-13 07:21:41.154  13226-13226/com.hbeat.hbeat I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42e7f528 time:435161647
04-13 07:21:41.154  13226-13226/com.hbeat.hbeat I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42ddbcf0 time:435161647
04-13 07:21:42.154  13226-13243/com.hbeat.hbeat I/GMPM﹕ Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
04-13 07:21:43.674  13226-13226/com.hbeat.hbeat W/FragmentActivity﹕ Activity result delivered for unknown Fragment.
04-13 07:21:43.694  13226-13226/com.hbeat.hbeat I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42e7f528 time:435164182
```

I am using latest play services(8.7.03) on my KITKAT device and building with 8.4.0(revision 29) which is shown as most recent in SDK Manager.

I have correctly added project in google developer console for this app.

Comment: where do you host this function activity or fragment? If you are using .enableAutoManage(..) you have to extend FragmentActivity.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google released new API and this issue is resolved in it. So just update your build.gradle file with:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.0.0'

Comment: Thank you for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `connect()` and `disconnect()` methods. Interfaces receives callbacks in response to the asynchronous `connect()` method when the connection to Google Play services succeeds, fails, or becomes suspended.

```
mClient.connect();
```

Sample codes and more information can be found in [Manually Managed Connections](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#manually_managed_connections).

Comment: I did that. Still the problem remains.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.